# Не рабтают прокси в file_get_contents

Tags: proxy, file-get-contents

Пытаюсь настроить получение контента с использованием file_get_contents и прокси.

Суть в чем, контент я получаю, все супер, но если прописываю 100% неработающие прокси, скрипт все равно работает как надо, тоесть игнорирует ошибку прокси и их не использует вообще...

```
$proxy = $parse['proxy'];

        $aContext = array(
            'https' => array(
                'proxy' => $proxy,
                'request_fulluri' => true,
            ),
        );
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$sFile = file_get_contents($url, false, $cxContext);
echo $sFile;
```

почему так? и как исправить?

**UP:**

добавил в код отображение заголовков

```
echo $url."<br>";
print_r($http_response_header)."<br>";
```

вот результат:

```
     https://dropmp3.ru/klubnaya-muzyka-novinki/page/1/

Array (
         [0] = HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
         [1] = Server: nginx/1.14.0
         [2] = Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 07:52:56 GMT
         [3] = Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
         [4] = Connection: close
         [5] = Location: http://dropmp3.ru/klubnaya-muzyka-novinki/
         [6] = Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
         [7] = HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
         [8] = Server: nginx/1.14.0
         [9] = Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 07:52:56 GMT
         [10] = Content-Type: text/html
         [11] = Connection: close
         [12] = Location: https://dropmp3.ru:443/klubnaya-muzyka-novinki/
         [13] = HTTP/1.1 200 OK
         [14] = Server: nginx/1.14.0
         [15] = Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 07:52:56 GMT
         [16] = Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
         [17] = Connection: close
         [18] = X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.38
         [19] = Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=s4o528pt5132ou2ur4tpjo8nq0; path=/; HttpOnly
         [20] = Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
         [21] = Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
         [22] = Pragma: no-cache
         [23] = Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; )

 https://dropmp3.ru/klubnaya-muzyka-novinki/page/2/

Array (
         [0] = HTTP/1.1 200 OK
         [1] = Server: nginx/1.14.0
         [2] = Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 07:52:56 GMT
         [3] = Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
         [4] = Connection: close
         [5] = X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.38
         [6] = Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=4q6n9sbk1dtpg85totjp4k33o2; path=/; HttpOnly
         [7] = Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
         [8] = Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
         [9] = Pragma: no-cache
         [10] = Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; )
```

собственно вопрос: **как понять как обрабатывать случаи "прокси не работает"**
чтоб в случае если прокси не рабочие, запрос не проводился, а віводилось сообщение об ошибке

Comment: полученный результат чекать нужно - на контрольный кусок текста, на код 200-301-302...

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил ответ сервера

Comment: Так что вы хотите? 1) Чекать не работающие прокси, 2) понять как обрабатывать случаи "прокси не работает", 3) или что-то еще. Я вижу что везде 200, все ОК. В первом примере 2 редиректа было.

Comment: И да, хотите что-то более устойчивое, то НЕ используйте `file_get_content`, иначе придется дописывать кучу всего. Попробуйте другой инструмент. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#proxy

Comment: 2) понять как обрабатывать случаи "прокси не работает",

Comment: чтоб в случае если прокси не рабочие, запрос не проводился, а віводилось сообщение об ошибке